# What path does vscode use when installing packages?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

(First question on here.)

I'm using vscode on Windows to program in python. 
My Windows username has spaces in it and so I have to use double quotes in most paths, and have changed my pythonPath and fileName path accordingly. But when I'm prompted to install packages (pylint, etc.), the terminal shows errors, due to the spaces in the path.

I have been searching the settings for the path to the extensions, if that's what I need to modify, but can't find it.

This is the terminal response, when I click Install on the 'Linter pylint not installed' popup:

```
(venv)C:\PythonScripts\YTHistory>c:/PythonScripts/YTHistory/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:\Users\firstName lastName\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U pylint

C:\Users\firstName lastName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\firstName': [Errno 2] No
such file or directory
```

(I can make it work by just putting double quotes after the second path, but I would like to figure how I can get that out of the way)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a virtual environment then you don't need to tell any tool about a specific path. Just install into your virtual environment and VS Code will use it from there, e.g. `python -m pip install pylint` from an activated terminal.

If you're not using a virtual environment then I advise you use one first, then install your development tools into it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using a virtual environment and don't face any problems when manually using the terminal. It is when using vscode features and accempting the install prompts from vscode that I face problems/

Comment: That shouldn't play into it. Can you edit your question to show the output from the terminal?

Comment: I have added the terminal output. Is it helpful?

Comment: That's a bug in the extension due to a recent change. You can file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python to help use fix it. Do make sure you have the latest version of the extension installed, though, as we fixed a similar issue to this earlier in the week.